# How much to raise pre-flop in a late position with a reasonably good but not outstanding hand?

Tags: texas-hold-em, pre-flop, raise

I am a beginner who's learning to play Hold'em Poker by playing fake money games at Pokerstars.

Suppose there are 6 of us and I am at the button. I have QJo. Everyone before me limps. I want to play this hand and also to kick out as many opponents as I can pre-flop. I'm raising 3bb pre-flop (online recommendations). What often happens to me is that many opponents call me in such situation. I suspect their logic (right or not) might be that investing another 2bb to call is not a big deal given that they've already invested 1bb.

I rarely win such hand post-flop, especially if the flop is like T43, opponents call me with hands like Q4, 33, A2, and they now have a pair, trips, a straight draw, etc.

What I tried is to raise more than 3bb pre-flop (e.g. 6bb). That does help to eliminate more opponents but it also seems that I am dumping more money into the pot without having the best hand.

What would be a good strategy to play such hand pre-flop when you are in position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best size is : 3x pot..
If there is 2limp , pot is (2bb + 1,5bb sb and bb) total = 3,5bb

3 x 3,5(pot) = 10,5bb .

10bb or 10,5bb is a good size to squeeze.

When u are OOP (out of position) use 3,5 or 4x pot

When u are IP (in position)  2.7 or 3x pot

When play at low level , people rarely fold.
Use a big size , play tighter and better select hands.

Search more articles on odds and equity.. ;)

Comment: `best size is : 3x pot`, where did you learn this rule from?

Comment: Poker and rule are conflicting words. If u want , u can go all in after 2 limp. No one prevents you. The idea behind Raise is -> generate fold equity.  In the example. pot after u raise is 14bb (10,5 u rasise + 0,5bb for sb + 1bb for bb and 2bb for limpers). For your opponent need to add 9,5bb to defende in a pot 23,5 (14bb+ 9,5bb for call). 
9,5 / 23,5 = 0,40  * 100 =  40% is the minimum equity required to call. What does it mean?? it means that your opponent 
gives you a range (AA,KK,QQ,AK,AQ,KQ,and so on..) 
and it needs a range that have 40% minimum equity vs your range. 
That's theory